# Cordova/Phonegap Android Parse Push Notification not resuming app

Tags: cordova, android-activity, push-notification, parse-platform, phonegap-plugins

I'm using Parse for push notifications in my Cordova Android app. The notifications are arriving fine, but when one is tapped to open the app, it is opened with a black screen.

When I hit the Android device back button the black screen goes and the cordova app appears from behind. So the app doesn't seem to be just resuming, but opening a blank Activity, I think.

I'm using the following plugin: **https://github.com/benjie/phonegap-parse-plugin**, plus I've added a few extra lines to the main activity class, included below:

```
package com.mycompany.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import org.apache.cordova.*;

import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseAnalytics;
import com.parse.ParseInstallation;
import com.parse.PushService;

public class MyApp extends CordovaActivity 
{
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        super.init();
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());

        // register device for parse
        Parse.initialize(this, APP_ID, PRIVATE_KEY);
        PushService.setDefaultPushCallback(this, MyApp.class);
        ParseAnalytics.trackAppOpened(getIntent());
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
    }
}
```

So what can I do to just get the app to come back from the background, without trying to take any specific action and showing this black screen on top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, this is the expected outcome as far as I can tell from the parse documentation

> When the client receives a push message, a notification will appear
>   in the system tray. When the  user taps the notification, they will
>   enter the application through a *new instance of  YourActivity.*

From: https://parse.com/docs/android/api/com/parse/PushService.html

So the key thing there being, it creates a new instances, which I'm assuming tries to load my index.html, but there's no Cordova initialisation or deviceReady as the app itself is already running.

When I find a work around I will post it.

**UPDATE**

I was wrong, I had the following setting in my config.xml:

```
<preference name="KeepRunning" value="false"/>
```

Removing that fixed it, as it defaults to `true`. From the Cordova docs:

> KeepRunning (boolean, defaults to true): Determines whether the
>   application stays running in the background even after a pause event
>   fires. Setting this to false does not kill the app after a pause
>   event, but simply halts execution of code within the cordova webview
>   while the app is in the background.

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_config.md.html#Android%20Configuration